# Cross validation on unbalanced datasets using a simulation approach on a subset of data

Tags: regression, cross-validation, random-variable, simulation, sample

Within my field I often end up using linear regression to look at two variables, normally how some factor (e.g. size) changes through time. I'm increasingly coming across datasets that are unbalanced in that there are many samples in recent years, but few samples in older years:

```
size <- c(4.444,  0.757,  0.863,  0.466, 1.664, 0.455, 1.375, 0.817, 0.866, 1.254, 9.85, 0.622, 0.546, 0.498,
  0.914, 0.905, 0.945, 0.566, 1.652, 0.709, 1.219, 1.918, 0.653, 0.638, 0.697, 1.063, 0.570,
  0.5563, 0.670, 0.448,  0.432, 0.423, 1.619, 0.434, 0.498, 0.5123333, 0.420, 0.452, 0.914,  0.512,  
  0.414, 1.494, 0.410, 0.422, 1.126, 1.718, 1.938, 15.018, 0.412, 1.101, 0.421, 7.812, 5.212,8.345, 6.212)

year <- c(1974, 1982, 1988, 1985, 1966, 1988, 1978, 2008, 1979, 1990, 1952, 1971, 1994, 1966, 1981, 1995, 1976, 
         2003, 1982, 1989, 2012, 1991, 1985, 2010, 1992, 1976, 1986, 1986, 1998, 1991, 1992, 1987, 1986, 1984,
         1997, 1986, 1991, 1988, 2002, 1994, 1994, 1988, 2007, 1984, 2013, 1984, 1976, 1963, 2006, 1987, 1982, 1976, 
         1961, 1958, 1965)

plot(size~year)
```

Which looks like this (this is an overly optimistic dummy dataset! often the data is far more unbalanced through time):

[image: dataplot]

To try and get at the question of sample sizes influencing regression analysis, my approach is to subsample the more recent data with the same n as in the early years. In the example above, there's 15 data points pre-1980, and 40 datapoints post-1980:

```
count(subset(df, year<1980))
count(subset(df, year>1980))
```

To do this I've written a loop that subsamples the post-1980 data with the same number of samples as pre-1980 and runs a linear regression on the subset, and then repeats this 1000 times as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(size,year)


p<-array(NA,dim=c(1000,1))
coefs<-array(NA,dim=c(1000,1))


count(subset(df, year<1980))
count(subset(df, year>1980))

for (i in 1:1000){

pre <- subset(df, df$year < 1980)
post <- subset(df, df$year > 1980)

postsubset <- post[sample(nrow(post), sample(nrow(pre), 1)), ]

newdf <- rbind(pre,postsubset)

  summary <-lm(log(size)~year, data = newdf)
  pvalues <- car::Anova(lm(log(size)~year, data = newdf))

coefs[i,] <- coef(summary)[[2]]
pvalues<- pvalues[[4]]
p[i,] <- pvalues[[1]]

}

sum(p < 0.05)/length(p)*100 # proportion of models that return a significant result

hist(coefs)
```

Am I right in thinking that this is cross-validation? To me this is a more robust way of approaching imbalanced data, but... what would be the best way of interpreting the results from this sort of analysis?

My two options so far have been 1) to look at the proportion of models that return a significant result, and 2) to plot the coefficients from the simulated models and see where the coefficients from the full data sit:

```
pvalues <- car::Anova(lm(log(size)~year, data = df))
coef(summary)[[2]]
hist(coefs)
abline(v=coef(summary)[[2]], col="red")
```

Like this:

[image: abline]

I'm probably re-inventing the wheel here and this approach has been used before, or there's a very good reason why people don't use this approach, but I haven't been able to find many applications. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated (the dummy dataset is a *very* optimistic scenario, often the data are much more unbalanced!)